# Invalid Stops in Breakeven function

Tags: mql5

When I'm testing EA ,and BreakEven option only  in the Jurnal section of strategy tester , I see error info about position modification: "  failed modify #28 sell 1.00 EURUSD sl: 1.14730, tp: 1.13730 -> sl: 1.14730, tp: 1.13730 [Invalid stops]

When I slow down strategy tester  break-even working well, and move stop loss on 0.  Everything works, but I see a bug report. 
If anyone knows to solve this problem, I would appreciate it.

thanks

input double break_even = 3.0;
double ExtBreakEven     = 0.0;

```
int Oninit()
{
//--- tuning for 3 or 5 digits
   int digits_adjust=1;
   if(_symbol.Digits()==3 || _symbol.Digits()==4 || _symbol.Digits()==5)
      digits_adjust=10;
      m_adjusted_point=_symbol.Point()*digits_adjust;
//--- 
   ExtBreakEven         = break_even          *   m_adjusted_point;
}                      

//..... and finally 
void BreakEven(const double price)
{ 
   if (break_even==0)
       return;
   for (int i=PositionsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--){
      string symbol=PositionGetSymbol(i);
      ulong magic=PositionGetInteger(POSITION_MAGIC);
      if (symbol==_symbol.Name() && magic == magic_number){
         ulong PositionTicket=PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TICKET);
         double PriceEntry=PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN);
         double CurrentTakeProfit=PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP);
         if (PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)==POSITION_TYPE_BUY){
            if (price>=(PriceEntry+ExtBreakEven)){
               if (!_trade.PositionModify(PositionTicket,PriceEntry,CurrentTakeProfit)) {
                   Print("Modify ",PositionTicket,
                                          " Position -> false. Result Retcode: ",_trade.ResultRetcode(),
                                          ", description of result: ",_trade.ResultRetcodeDescription());
                  PrintResultModify(_trade,_symbol,_position);
               }
            }
         }
         else {
         if (PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)==POSITION_TYPE_SELL){
            if (price<=(PriceEntry-ExtBreakEven)){
               if (!_trade.PositionModify(PositionTicket,PriceEntry,CurrentTakeProfit)){
                  Print("Modify ",PositionTicket,
                                          " Position -> false. Result Retcode: ",_trade.ResultRetcode(),
                                          ", description of result: ",_trade.ResultRetcodeDescription());
                  PrintResultModify(_trade,_symbol,_position);
               }
            }
         }
       }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the idea of moving SL from 1.14730 to 1.14730? They are absolutely the same. Maybe you can check the stoploss to understand that there is no need in moving the SL to the same value. Or you need another SL value, try to figure out why it remains the same

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I totally agree with you.It really doesn't make sense. Stop loss is placed below the open order. So the main idea is when the condition is met, the stop loss should be reset to zero and remain in line with the open order.

Comment: I do not see any place where you try to reset SL to zero (if you really need that). Easy solution is just to make sure that `PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN)>PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL)` before moving SL (case of buy).

Comment: Thank''s man. Now everything is okay and Break-Even working well,  and without any warning in the Strategy Tester.